# Google Drive API method Drive.File.update Can Silently Fail to Update File Content

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Using Java Google Drive API v2r109lv1.16.0-rc we have found that occasionally files are not updated correctly using the Drive.Files.update method. This seems to have occurred among customers sporadically since 22nd April 2014. Before then it was working just fine.

We are updating the file with new content and meta data. The meta data updates OK but the file content is not touched. There are no errors and as far as can be told the operation succeeds without an issue.

It is only when a user goes to access the file that a problem is seen by us. If for example the desired file content update is greater than the previous content then the meta information (file size) will be incorrect and the read will fail.

We are really struggling to create a reproduction scenario. Has anyone else experienced this problem, or know of a fix, or if Google has found an underlying problem that is (hopefully) fixed?

Comment: we're all seeing the same thing. It's not just media content, sometimes the meta data isn't being updated either.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if Google are aware and if there is forum fix progress can be tracked on?

Comment: I've seen comments from Googlers that they know about the problem. What I haven't seen is any detail on the specific characteristics of the problem (it seems to have a range of symptoms), and there is nowhere to track the status formally. I would guess that there will be some kind of apology on https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107264319205603895037?cfem=1 at some point

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced this issue is reliably fixed.

I would really like some clarity from google. This is a very bad problem. Data appears to be being lost, and file meta data and the actual data stream are out of sync.

Comment: We temporarily reverted back to use the update method described above and again we got reports that the method is still broken. Are you still seeing it @pinoyyid?