# My Google Drive app is no longer able to update google documents

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Yesterday afternoon I started having a problem where my google drive app could no longer update google documents. I can still update other file types like docx or rtf. This also happened to a coworker here but two different users are still able to use the google drive app and update google documents without issue, and we're all using the same build.

I logged into one of the working google accounts instead of my own and was not able to update that same google document that a coworker was able to. However the coworker that was having the same problem as me logged into a different google account and he was able to update google documents with the same build as before.

What the hell has happened here all of a sudden? This was working for us all two days ago.

This is where I request permissions:

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
                StoredCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new SavedDataStore()).Result;
```

I know the fileID going into it so:

```
request = service.Files.Get(fileID);
myFile = request.Execute();
```

While working with google documents I download it as a docx file and so:

```
if (myFile.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.document")
    myFile.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
```

And this is where the update happens:

```
try
        {
            //fileLoc contains the updated contents
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileLoc);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
            FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload updateRequest = service.Files.Update(myFile, fileID, stream, myFile.MimeType);
            //fileID is used to get myFile in the first place; myFile is = to myFile.Id
            updateRequest.Upload();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
```

This request happens without throwing any error and even updates the timestamp on these files but the content does not update. I am losing my mind trying to figure this out, I don't know what has gone wrong and I have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: This sounds very much like the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266388/google-drive-api-method-drive-file-update-can-silently-fail-to-update-file-conte), which still seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary glitch, this should be working again now.

Comment: Thank you, I feel foolish for having spent the last 24 hours losing my mind over this

Comment: Cheryl, are you sure this is fixed? We have indications that it isnt, that there are some files still being effected. Do you have any details you could share with us?